# Django CSRF error on form submission

Tags: python, django

I am writing a Django app. Here is my code:

**edit.module.html** (template; removing extra html markup):

```
<h1>Enter the HTML below</h1>
<form action="./update/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea cols='55' rows='15'></textarea>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^myapp/update/$', 'myproj.myapp.views.update_module'),
```

**view.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.template import RequestContext

#Select the module you want to edit
def edit_modules(request):
    lpconf = {"module_to_edit" : "top"}
    return render_to_response('admin/edit.module.html', lpconf, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def update_module(request):
    return render_to_response('admin/updated.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I submit the form I get CSRF error: "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

I followed the Django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) and tried to fix the problem but I couldn't. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks.

UPDATE: Updated view.py functions edit_modules and update_modules. edit_modules is the one rendering the form and update_modules is the one processing it. Now, I am not getting CSRF error. I am now getting the error: **Empty module name**

UPDATE: I was able to fix it. I was using one view to render the form and another one to process it. I had to add context to the first view that was rendering the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `RequestContext` in your `update_module` view, rather than a plain old `HttpResponse`. If you use the handy [render shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render), it will be added automatically. There's a nice and quick intro to this in the Django tutorial; [A shortcut: render()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render).

Comment: Do I need to pass an actual template html file to make this work? Can't I just pass some text message without having to use an actual HTML file?

Comment: You probably should define a proper HTML template, it wouldn't take a moment to create one in your templates directory!

Comment: Yeah I just did and in the view I updated the code to "return render(request, 'updated.html')". Sill same CSRF error. I also imported "from django.shortcuts import render"

Comment: @Leon The Django tutorial for [form handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form) might come in useful. You should be checking in your update_module view whether the form was posted and if not, rendering the form.

Comment: @Leon It looks as though you must be rendering the form itself with a separate view? I usually handle the processing and rendering of a POST form with the same view and just use `HttpResponseRedirect` on success. Perhaps this is the trouble?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the request context process in your settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (...
    "django.core.context_processors.request")
```

so you do not have to do:

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                      my_data_dictionary,
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Instead, simply:
    return render_to_response('my_template.html',
                          my_data_dictionary)

Also, make sure that 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' is enabled in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES in your settings.py